# how to stop I/O log container in kubernetes

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, logging, google-kubernetes-engine

when i access docker container in GKE like `kubectl exec -it [pod-name] bash -n seunghwan`
i see lots of logs(I don't know what it is)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3dvd.png)
this container I accessed have nodejs application but i tried mysql server it looks same.
I am the only one can see these logs. others can't see these logs so I think this problem is from my local
if need more info please tell me thank you

when i access container in GKE there are no logs in bash terminal.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use `kubectl exec -it [pod-name] -n seunghwan -- bash` as your command is deprecated?  
Also it looks like it's coming from your terminal with doesn't handle well as shell in a shell.  
Are you using a tolls form google to access it or a local terminal?

Comment: when i use `kubectl exec -it [pod-name] -n seunghwan -- bash` i got same logs.
I am using local terminal with gcloud SDK to access gke.

Comment: Which local terminal? Are you on windows or linux? Powershell, bash, zsh it is integrated inside an IDE?

Comment: i am using zsh on macOS

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce the issue by adding `DEBUG=true` before the exec command, such as:

```
DEBUG=true kubectl exec -it [pod-name] bash -n seunghwan
```

Try to set the DEBUG environment variable to `false` either at the beginning of your command or in your env var.

```
DEBUG=false kubectl exec -it [pod-name] bash -n seunghwan
```

Comment: i tried `DEBUG=false kubectl exec -it [pod-name] bash -n seunghwan` this but it does not working and i tried change .zshrc debug=false but it is not working