# Kubernetes@1 exec terminal printing network logs in pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, kubectl

Im running **Kubernetes@1** (Kubectl v1 task), and there is problem with logging the process on pod.

Example:

```
  - task: Kubernetes@1
    displayName: 'Execute ${{ parameters.triggerConfigName }}'
    timeoutInMinutes: ${{ parameters.triggerTestTimeout }}
    continueOnError: true 
    inputs:
      connectionType: Kubernetes Service Connection
      kubernetesServiceEndpoint: ${{ parameters.k8sService }}
      command: 'exec'
      arguments: 
        deploy/${{ parameters.chart_name }} -n ${{ parameters.namespace }} -- bash -c "PYTHONPATH=/code/src/ python3 -m someScript"
```

with this  task im getting normal logs mixed with network logs

---

[image]

my question is, what could be happening that this problem is happening?
In pod (/container) there is no other process running except for the one i run with the task)

---

EDIT1

further informations:

```
==============================================================================
Task         : Kubectl
Description  : Deploy, configure, update a Kubernetes cluster in Azure Container Service by running kubectl commands
Version      : 1.227.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azpipes-kubectl-tsg
==============================================================================
==============================================================================
            Kubectl Client Version: v1.25.12
            Kubectl Server Version: v1.27.3
==============================================================================
```

---

EDIT2

further informations:
with test via script, same result:

```
  - script: |
      #!/bin/bash
      kubectl config use-context ${{ parameters.k8sService }} 2>/dev/null
      kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=${{ parameters.namespace }}
      kubectl exec $(pod1) -n ${{ parameters.namespace }}  -- bash -c "PYTHONPATH=/code/src/ python3 -m someScript"
    name: test
```

---

```
I0314 10:17:33.759231  989283 log.go:194] (0xc0000c8000) (0xc0005941e0) Create stream
I0314 10:17:33.759310  989283 log.go:194] (0xc0000c8000) (0xc0005941e0) Stream added, broadcasting: 1
I0314 10:17:33.775142  989283 log.go:194] (0xc0000c8000) Reply frame received for 1
I0314 10:17:33.775186  989283 log.go:194] (0xc0000c8000) (0xc000594280) Create stream
I0314 10:17:33.775194  989283 log.go:194] (0xc0000c8000) (0xc000594280) Stream added, broadcasting: 3
I0314 10:17:33.789786  989283 log.go:194] (0xc0000c8000) Reply frame received for 3
I0314 10:17:33.789834  989283 log.go:194] (0xc0000c8000) (0xc000618000) Create stream
I0314 10:17:33.789844  989283 log.go:194] (0xc0000c8000) (0xc000618000) Stream added, broadcasting: 5
I0314 10:17:33.803261  989283 log.go:194] (0xc0000c8000) Reply frame received for 5
I0314 10:17:34.129360  989283 log.go:194] (0xc0000c8000) Data frame received for 5
I0314 10:17:34.129387  989283 log.go:194] (0xc000618000) (5) Data frame handling
I0314 10:17:34.129406  989283 log.go:194] (0xc000618000) (5) Data frame sent
2024-03-14 10:17:34,117 INFO     daemon Start
...
```

Comment: The [Kubernetes@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/kubernetes-v1?view=azure-pipelines) task should simply authenticate against your K8S service connection and establishes connection from your agent machine to the container to run `kubectl` command. Did the network logs output after the task ran `kuberctl exec` command or before? Were you able to observe the same behavior if running the command without using pipeline?

Comment: * running same command inside pod (with kubectl exec (bash)) -> normal log (without network intruder)
* network logs appeared out of nowhere, in one pipeline run, and are still there

Comment: found this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75037673/how-to-stop-i-o-log-container-in-kubernetes
seems like same problem

Comment: trying:

unset DEBUG and DEBUG=false kubectl exec ... and without change

Comment: Hi howard, have you got a chance to test with another namespace/pod/namesacpe? My pipeline that ran on MS-hosted agent to connect my AKS cluster (v1.27.9) and ran a very simple command `kuberctl exec $(pod1) -n ${{ parameters.namespace }} -- ls`, didn't reproduce the issue. The issue may come with your build environment or something else we haven't discussed?